# rbx.lua How to Find the x,y,z of the mouse without clicking (loop)

Tags: lua, roblox

I've been searching for a way to get the coordinates of the mouse so i can teleport a part to the mouse for my game. All i have found is GetMouse() which I don't really understand. By the way I'am new to rolblox lua.

```
Player = game.Players.LocalPlayer
Mouse = Player:GetMouse()
MousePos = Mouse.Hit
print (MousePos)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Alright, well first off I'm assuming your code is in a localscript (that's how it should be). ':GetMouse()' simply gets the player's mouse. The mouse has different properties, and events.

You can get the CFrame of the mouse by doing:

```
local MouseCFrame = Mouse.Hit
```

CFrame values contain more than just the position of the mouse in real world space though. CFrame values contain position, and rotation. We can get the position by doing:

```
local MousePosition = MouseCFrame.p
```

We use the 'p' property of a CFrame value to get the position of that CFrame value. Quite useful. So, your final code is:

```
local Player = game.Players.LocalPlayer -- Also, I noticed you weren't using 'local' to define your variables. Use that, as it sets the variable apart from a global variable.
local Mouse = Player:GetMouse()
local MouseCFrame = Mouse.Hit
local MousePosition = MouseCFrame.p
print (MousePosition)
```

Hope I helped! :)